# How to access an own namespace in different applications but same project?

Tags: .net, vb.net, namespaces

I have two Applications. Applications1 owns `Namespace SelfMade` now I want to import that Namespace in Application2 but cannot find it. I tried `Imports SelfMade` but vb cannot find the Namespace. How I can access my namespace in Application2?

Example of my Namespace:

```
Namespace testNS
Public Class Triangle

    Public Length As Double
    Friend Height As Double
    Private Option As Double

End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a reference to Application 1 in Application 2

(Right click on application 2 in solution explorer and click add reference, then select Projects and then select Application 1)

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is more info on msdn

Comment: Just one more question. I set the reference and Imports NamespaceNS works but after Dim test As New Triangle i cannot access the members. InteliSense gives me nothing at "test."  Do you know why and how i can fix this.

Comment: Check if those members are marked as public. (Length is in your sample though) otherwise try rebuilding